# Sent ETH to a multisig wallet of wrong network

Tags: gnosis-safe, error, network

I made a mistake to sent 4.32ETH from Arbitrum One to a Ethereum safe wallet(eth address: 0xb393D80cAB42233Ba1E2EE1d0cac18e10e20ADD6),
the safe wallet creation hash is 0xc0ef3c55ae988b6671e7c25f685376ceebfa83758d44a033c7429bbe7a33254c(Ethereum), and I tried to
create same address multisig wallet on Arbitrum followed the lession(https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741), I tried 3 times,
the transactions are always success, but the wallet addresses are always different. One of my transaction hash is https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x7cd8a842e190748882fb4f910c63e3e9a1741c011fffe71ea203c95e3c40fa88. Could anyone help me to recover my fund?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: stop trying. The more you try (without being certain of success), the more chances there are that it will be impossible to get the desired address anymore.

I'm not familiar with the exact mechanism how the contract is deployed, but I would suggest the folloing:

1. As said, stop trying in mainnet immediately
2. Research how the contract is deployed and how its address is derived
3. Fork the desired mainnet locally and start trying to create the contract there. Reset the fork when needed.

This may not be easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at this: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover